# How to get the payload type in redux typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using react typescript with the redux store. I have two types of object types coming from the payload. I want to identify the payload object type so that I can do some action based on the type.

These are the types

```
type Car = {
  carID: number,
  color: string,
  model: string,
  score: number
}

type Bus = {
  busID: number,
  model: string,
  type: string
}

type Transports = {
    [id: number]: Array<Car | Bus>;
}

interface State  {
  data: Transports
}
```

and in the reducer, I have a delete method in which I am getting an error:
`Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.`
`Type 'Car | Bus' is not assignable to type 'Car'.`
on forEach loop

```
deleteVehicle: (state: State, action: PayloadAction<Car | Bus>) => {
      if("carID" in action.payload){
        const { id, carID } = action.payload;
        let vehicles = { ...state.data };
        vehicles[id].forEach((x: Car) => {
         if (x.carID === carID) x.score = 0;
       });
      state.data = { ...vehicles };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if a key exists so Typescript will infer the correct type. This is called a type guard.

```js
deleteVehicle: (state: State, action: PayloadAction<Car | Bus>) => {
  const { id, carID } = action.payload;

  const vehicles = state.data;
  
  return {
    ...vehicles,
    vehicles[id]: vehicles[id].map((vehicule) => {
      if ('carId' in vehicule && vehicule.carId === carId) {
        // vehicule will be of type Car
        vehicule.score = 0;
      }

      return vehicule;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It check both side, is availble in type `Car` bu not `Bus` ,

Solution 1 : made a condition ( if type is bus it call `x.busID` instead of `x.carID` ).

Solution 2 : change both  type to get a common  id